# IIS The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf, iis

I have an application that receives json files from another application via an API. I tried changing the settings inside the web.config file but when I'm trying to move a bigger json file I receive this error. Could someone look over this config and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="Data Source=x.x.x.xxx;Persist Security Info=True;Password=1234;User ID=serv;Initial Catalog=app" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/WopDatabase.csdl|res://*/WopDatabase.ssdl|res://*/WopDatabase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=x.x.x.xxx;initial catalog=app;persist security info=True;user id=serv;password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Wop_Service.InformationsService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="InformationsService" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="Wop_Service.IInformationsService">
        

        </endpoint>


        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:4443/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mexHttpsBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
    <serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" maxUrl="2147483647" maxQueryString="2147483647" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <asp>
            <limits maxRequestEntityAllowed="2147483647" requestQueueMax="2147483647" />
            <cache maxDiskTemplateCacheFiles="2147483647" enableTypelibCache="false" />
        </asp>
        <caching maxCacheSize="0" maxResponseSize="2147483647" />
  </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime appRequestQueueLimit="2147483647" executionTimeout="3710" maxRequestLength="2147483647" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="2147483647" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" maxUrlLength="260000" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How big is the Json file your API receives?

Comment: 115-150 KB, but I think is correlated with the number of lines that each file has. I think, when the json has over 75 lines it throws this error.